# tlmgr update problem

Tags: texlive, updating

Anytime there is a failure to update a package TeXlive 2013, and try to reinstall through `-reinstall-forcibly-removed` command, it complains that it cannot install the file in question, as per the attached error message:

> ```
> [18/22, 10:41/11:01] auto-install: tex4ht (33024) [872k] ... xzdec: (stdin): Une
> xpected end of input
> tar: Only read 5492 bytes from archive C:\Users\Robynet\AppData\Local\Temp\Ceq_m
> pa70v\tex4ht.tar
> untar: untarring C:\Users\Robynet\AppData\Local\Temp\Ceq_mpa70v\tex4ht.tar faile
> d (in C:\texlive\2013)
> TLPDB::_install_package: couldn't unpack http://ctan.megagod.net/tex-archive/sys
> tems/texlive/tlnet/archive/tex4ht.tar.xz to C:/texlive/2013
> tlmgr.pl: couldn't install new package tex4ht
> ```

As the problem with `tex4ht` started a couple of week ago, I supposed at the beginning was the problem with the Thai server. Last week I was in England, and the Oxford server, or whatever was serving Oxford Uni, gave me the same error. The same happened today for `pgfplots` package.
So I was wondering what should be the procedure in order to let those two packages install.

Comment: You seem to have some network problems. Try to solve them first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something which is almost certainly a network error.